# What framework does Facebook use on touch.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, html, touch

Is it jQuery or some custom HTML5 framework?

Answer (score 0):

It is custom javascript. I don't think they use JQuery or any framework. They are very concerned about performance so they tend to get right down to the metal. If you view the source of the page you will see that they have about 30 js files referenced. Most of their site, including touch, uses HTML5 when available for certain things. If you want to know more, you are going to have to dig through their source code.